# Get the "outest" window object in html document

Tags: javascript

If I have a document with for example 2 or more `Iframe`s in each other, how can I access the main document's `window` object from the last one down the tree?

```
<html>

...

<iframe>
    <iframe>
        <!-- I'm here -->
    </iframe>
</iframe>

...
```

I want to be able to redirect the browser window to another page but I cant seem to find a way to grab it's window object.

I tried something like

```
var outest = window;
if(outest.parent){
    outest = outest.parent
}
```

But for some reason it appears that `window` has infinite parents. Any ideas?

Comment: [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top) is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: @Teemu why put this as a comment rather than an answer? P.S.: does your name have anything to do with the most annoying thing on the planet? :D

Comment: I don't know, depends on what you keep the most annoying thing on the planet? The name itself is quite popular first name in Finland though.

Comment: @Teemu Teemo appears to be the name of one of the characters in a pretty popular game "League of Legends" and is the most hated one `:D` https://www.google.com/search?q=Teemo&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=a5wAVKjgKuPuyQOm-YCAAg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top) refers to the outmost `window` object, i.e. the browser window.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I can do this with `document` also? Sadly there's no `top` property there `:<`